# How to make scroll upto selected textfield using TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView in swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have added `pod 'TPKeyboardAvoidingSwift' in project in storyboard added view hierarchy like below
[image]

for scrollContainerview constraints

```
top, leading, trailing, bottom = 0 (safe area)
```

for scroll view i have given class name and constraints

```
top, leading, trailing, bottom = 0 (superview)
```

if i add view in side scrollview it shows redline

here how to add scrollview and how to give constraints

how to make selected textfield scroll up to keyboard using TPKeyboardAvoidingSwift.

please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Pod instead, [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/blob/master/README.md)

It literally only needs 1 line of code in AppDelegate and you are good to go, no need to do any further handling